# Highcharts - get bottom position for each stacked category

Tags: html, css, highcharts

[my current jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WxWvQ/13/)

I am trying to lower each price's data label to the bottom of each stacked category.

The problem with using absolute position is that every category has different dynamic height (data comes from db).

```
formatter: function() {
                        return '<div style="text-align: center; position: relative; top:9px">'+ this.series.name +
                               '</div><div style="text-align: center; position: relative; left: -63px; top:-10px; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; width:70px;">$'+ this.y +'</div>';
                    },
```

Also i don't want to use verticalAlign:bottom because i need the inner data label to be in the middle of each column, so i have the opposite problem here (middling the inner data label).

- ignore the fact that only the top price is visible. no idea why its not working in jsfiddle, works fine in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would achieve this by using a separate series for the secondary data labels:

**Example:**

```
    {
      type: 'scatter',
      data: [
        [-0.05, 0],
        [-0.05, 1465],
        [-0.05, 4454],
        [-0.05, 3116],
        [-0.05, 3498]
      ]
    }
```

**Updated Fiddle:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/WxWvQ/17/

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: awesome, exactly what i needed

Answer (score 1):

You can access the coordinates of each stack via `this.point.shapeArgs`. The bottom is `shapeArgs.y + shapeArgs.height` - the stacks are placed in the group which is translated - so you need to adjust the position of the group translation `this.point.series.group` (it has `translateX` and `translateY`)

My solution does not use the formatter, instead it creates custom labels and position them. The elements are svg elements, not html.

The funciton for making labels:

```
  function makeStackLabels() {
    const chart = this,
      renderer = chart.renderer,
      labels = chart.stackLabelsRendered,
      series = chart.series,
      lineLength = 75;

    if (!labels) {
      series.forEach(series => {
        const point = series.data[0];
        if (point) {
          point.label = renderer.g().add(series.group);
          renderer.path({
            d: 'M 0 0 L ' + lineLength + ' 0',
            stroke: 'black',
            'stroke-width': 1
          }).add(point.label);

          const text = renderer.text('$' + point.y, -9999, -5).add(point.label);
          text.attr({
            x: (lineLength - text.getBBox().width) / 2
          }).css({
            fontSize: '11px',
            fontWeight: 'bold'
          })
        }
      })
      chart.stackLabelsRendered = true;
    }

    series.filter(series => series.visible).forEach((series, i, arr) => {
      const point = series.data[0];
      const label = point && point.label;
      if (label) {
        const shapeArgs = point.shapeArgs;
        point.label.attr({
          translateX: shapeArgs.x - label.getBBox().width,
          translateY: shapeArgs.y + shapeArgs.height - (i === arr.length - 1 ? 1: 0) // for the last label we need to move it up a little so the line wont be clipped
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

Set the function on load and redraw

```
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'column',
    events: {
      load: makeStackLabels,
      redraw: makeStackLabels
    }
  },
```

#### Live example and output

http://jsfiddle.net/w28hmp94/

[image: custom stack labels]

Comment: great solution though its complicated for me to continue from here, because i need to do some more styling here (stretch this line instead of the existing categories borders) and i haven't learnt svg at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can change a bit formater function to have you $ amount inside serie div. 
But it's not perfectly align with box...

```js
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'
            },
            
            xAxis: {
             title: null,
                        lineWidth: 0,
                        minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                        gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                        lineColor: 'transparent',
                        labels: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        minorTickLength: 0,
                        tickLength: 0
            },
            
            yAxis: {
             title: null,
                        lineWidth: 0,
                        minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                        gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                        lineColor: 'transparent',
                        labels: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        minorTickLength: 0,
                        tickLength: 0
            },
            
            legends: {enabled: false},
           
            plotOptions: {

                series: {

                    lineWidth: 15,

                },
                column: {

                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        useHTML: true,
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<div style="text-align: center; position: relative; top:9px;">'
                            + this.series.name
                            + '<div style="position: relative; left: -70px; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; width:70px;top:0px">$'
                            + this.y 
                            + '</div></div>';
                        },
                    },

                    pointWidth: 50,
                },
            },
            series: [{

                name: '+8',
                data: [3656],

            }, {

                name: '5-8',
                data: [3498],

            }, {

                name: '3-5',
                data: [3116],

            }, {

                name: '1-3',
                data: [4454],

            }, {

                name: '0',
                data: [1465],

            }

            ]
        });
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: the bottom align is the main issue here. lets say i change the data in name: '0', from 1465 to 13465, everything is messed up